# Avoiding unnecessary key evaluations when sorting a list

Tags: python, sorting, python-2.7, lazy-evaluation

I have a list which I want to sort by multiple `key`s, like:

```
L = [ ... ]
L.sort(key = lambda x: ( f(x), g(x) ))
```

This works fine. However, this results with unnecessary calls to `g`, which I would like to avoid (for being potentially slow). In other words, I want to *partially and lazily* evaluate the key.

For example, if `f` is unique over `L` (i.e. `len(L) == len(set(map(f,L)))`) no calls to `g` should be made.

*What would be the most elegant/pythonic way to do this?*

---

One way I can think of is to define a custom `cmp` function (`L.sort(cmp=partial_cmp)`), but IMO this is less elegant and more complicated than using the `key` parameter.

Another way would be to define a key-wrapper class which takes a generator expression to generate the different parts of the key, and override the comparison operators to compare one-by-one. However, I'm feeling there must be a simpler way...

---

EDIT: I'm interested in a solution for the general problem of sorting by *multiple* functions, not only two as in my example above.

Comment: Actually as far as I know ``cmp`` version might be slower than ``key`` version, as ``key`` is evaluated N times, and ``cmp`` ``O(log(n)n)`` times.

Comment: @jb. Isn't Python's sort O(nlogn)?

Comment: @jb interesting. However, for my specific case we can assume `g` is significantly slower than comparing the results of `f` and `g` (besides, I can cache the results in a wrapper object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a function, you could create a LazyComparer class like this:

```
def lazy_func(func):
    class LazyComparer(object):
        def __init__(self, x):
            self.x = x
        def __lt__(self, other):
            return func(self.x) < func(other.x)
        def __eq__(self, other):
            return func(self.x) == func(other.x)
    return lambda x: LazyComparer(x)
```

To make a lazy key function out of multiple functions, you could create a utility function:

```
def make_lazy(*funcs):
    def wrapper(x):
        return [lazy_func(f)(x) for f in funcs]
    return wrapper
```

And together they could be used like this:

```
def countcalls(f):
    "Decorator that makes the function count calls to it."
    def _f(*args, **kwargs):
        _f._count += 1
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    _f._count = 0
    return _f

@countcalls
def g(x): return x

@countcalls
def f1(x): return 0

@countcalls
def f2(x): return x

def report_calls(*funcs):
    print(' | '.join(['{} calls to {}'.format(f._count, f.func_name)
                      for f in funcs]))

L = range(10)[::-1]

L.sort(key=make_lazy(f1, g))
report_calls(f1, g)

g._count = 0
L.sort(key=make_lazy(f2, g))
report_calls(f2, g)
```

which yields

```
18 calls to f1 | 36 calls to g
36 calls to f2 | 0 calls to g
```

The @countcalls decorator above is used to connfirm that when `f1` returns a lot
of ties, `g` is called to break the ties, but when `f2` returns distinct values,
`g` does not get called.

---

NPE's solution adds memoization within the `Key` class. With the solution above,
you could add memoization outside (independent of) the `LazyComparer` class:

```
def memo(f):
    # Author: Peter Norvig
    """Decorator that caches the return value for each call to f(args).
    Then when called again with same args, we can just look it up."""
    cache = {}
    def _f(*args):
        try:
            return cache[args]
        except KeyError:
            cache[args] = result = f(*args)
            return result
        except TypeError:
            # some element of args can't be a dict key
            return f(*args)
    _f.cache = cache
    return _f

L.sort(key=make_lazy(memo(f1), memo(g)))
report_calls(f1, g)
```

which results in fewer calls to `g`:

```
10 calls to f1 | 10 calls to g
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try using [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

```
result = []
for groupKey, group in groupby(sorted(L, key=f), key=f):
    sublist = [y for y in group]
    if len(sublist) > 1:
        result += sorted(sublist, key=g)
    else:
        result += sublist
```

Another possibility, even less elegant, but in place:

```
L.sort(key = f)
start = None
end = None
for i,x in enumerate(L):
    if start == None:
        start = i
    elif f(x) == f(L[start]):
        end = i
    elif end == None:
        start = i
    else:
        L[start:end+1] = sorted(L[start:end+1], key=g)
        start = None
if start != None and end != None:
    L[start:end+1] = sorted(L[start:end+1], key=g)
```

First version generalized to any number of functions:

```
def sortBy(l, keyChain):
    if not keyChain:
        return l

    result = []
    f = keyChain[0]
    for groupKey, group in groupby(sorted(l, key=f), key=f):
        sublist = [y for y in group]
        if len(sublist) > 1:
            result += sortBy(sublist, keyChain[1:])
        else:
            result += sublist
    return result
```

The second version generalized to any number of functions (not fully in place though):

```
def subSort(l, start, end, keyChain):
    part = l[start:end+1]
    sortBy(part, keyChain[1:])
    l[start:end+1] = part

def sortBy(l, keyChain):
    if not keyChain:
        return

    f = keyChain[0]
    l.sort(key = f)

    start = None
    end = None
    for i,x in enumerate(l):
        if start == None:
            start = i
        elif f(x) == f(l[start]):
            end = i
        elif end == None:
            start = i
        else:
            subSort(l, start, end, keyChain)
            start = i
            end = None
    if start != None and end != None:
        subSort(l, start, end, keyChain)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a key object that would lazily evaluate and cache `g(x)`:

```
class Key(object):
  def __init__(self, obj):
    self.obj = obj
    self.f = f(obj)
  @property
  def g(self):
    if not hasattr(self, "_g"):
      self._g = g(self.obj)
    return self._g
  def __cmp__(self, rhs):
    return cmp(self.f, rhs.f) or cmp(self.g, rhs.g)
```

Here is an example of use:

```
def f(x):
  f.count += 1
  return x // 2
f.count = 0

def g(x):
  g.count += 1
  return x
g.count = 0

L = [1, 10, 2, 33, 45, 90, 3, 6, 1000, 1]
print sorted(L, key=Key)
print f.count, g.count
```